# Angular 9, action not triggered until next click

Tags: angular

I have a preexisting code, and the problem are as listed:

- Transparent loading screen not closing until next click on the body,
- Select box options data doesn't listed until next click on the
  body/selectbox,
- Toast notification popup doesn't show until next click on the body.

All these problems happen only in one component, other components using the same library/function are working well.

I tried console log in all the above functions from start to finish, and it go through all the functions, it's like there's nothing wrong.

I found a question on other site with the same exact problem on the notification like me, but there's no answer.

Any idea why this "event triggered only on next click" happened? Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to mention that eventho toast not working, toastr is working without the next trigger click, but I can't make toastr css work, it's in my other question.

Snippet of my component function:

```
public loadPeriod() {
    const me = this;
    const query_params = {};
    query_params['day'] = '1';
    query_params['class'] = '3';

    this.http.get(this.url.getUrl(this.url.StudyPeriod), {
        onStart: function() {
        },
        onSuccess: function(data) {
            console.dir(data);
            
            //me.toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!', {timeOut: 10000});
            //toastr working, but no styling
            
            console.log('toast 1');
            me.message_service.addToast('', 'Period Editor', 'Period has been loaded', 'success', null, 'sp-editor');
            //toast not working until next click
            console.log('toast 5');
        },
        onCompleted: function() {
        }
    }, {
        params: query_params
    }, this.cookie_service, this.config_service);
}
```

My toast service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MessageService} from 'primeng/api';
import {Observable, Observer, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import OptMessageArgs from './opt-message-args';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class OptMessageService {
    constructor(private msg_service: MessageService) {}

    private _message_listener_source: Subject<OptMessageArgs> = new Subject();
    public message_listener: Observable<OptMessageArgs> = this._message_listener_source.asObservable();

    addToast(id: string, title: string, details: string
        , severities: string = 'info', data: any = null
        , key: string = 'root-bottom-left', duration: number = 3000
        , closable: boolean = true, sticky: boolean = false) {
        const now: Date = new Date();
        
        console.log('2');
        
        this._message_listener_source.next({
            id: id,
            time: now,
            data: data
        });
        
        console.log('3');

        this.msg_service.add({
            severity: severities,
            summary: title,
            detail: details,
            id: id,
            key: key,
            life: duration,
            closable: closable,
            data: data,
            sticky: sticky
        });
        
        console.log('4');
    }

    clearToast(key: string) {
        this.msg_service.clear(key);
    }
}
```

console.log result: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: The reason it works on the next click is because Angular activates the change detector mechanism after each user interaction. Possibly, after the change detector is running, the toast component is activated without Angular's knowledge.I need to see your codes to help me further.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL I've edited my question and added some code snippet. I've found a suggestion to add timeout to toast, but still not working until next click.

Comment: What http client are you using?

Comment: @AndreiTătar import { HttpClient, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

It just made into service, but there is a function using HttpClient without service in the same component. Notification still get the same problem.

Comment: do you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` anywhere in the component tree?

Comment: @AndreiTătar It did it. I just commented the line. Thank you so much, This is a preexisting code and I'm not familiar with Angular.

Comment: @v1n_vampire if you use `OnPush` you should just notify the `ChangeDetectorRef` that a change happened and it should mark the component for recheck. There are lots of articles about this.

Answer (score 0):

See comment on first post.

I commented/delete this line and it worked.

```
ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Thank you to [@AndreiTătar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016654/andrei-t%C4%83tar)